# How can I hide the full url of my website?

Tags: html

When I upload my website files to my server and goto my website, i see the index.html at the url bar of the browser. How can I hide this?

http://bakpinar.com/about/about-us.html

I would like it to look like in this example;

http://www.royaltyline.com

as you can see, you only see the website address in the url bar of the browser. And when you click to another page, it doesnt show the .php, .asp or .html extension, just shows the folder name.

Comment: No you can't. Imagine spoofing `https://yourbank.com/` instead of `http://fakesite.com/`. The only way to see a different URL is to proxy the response, or putting it in a frame.

Comment: The only way to "hide" your URL would be to use frames. But the real question is: Why do you want to do that? There's no real reason to "hide" the full URL.

Comment: I don't think they're asking to make their URL go to a different URL, they're asking for cleaner URLs, using the other bank as an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To hide the extension shown in the address bar, you have two options.

1. If you control the server, you can define rules that rewrite the URL based on the one the user is trying to get to. In PHP you can use the .htaccess file to define mod_rewrite rules. For similar features to .htaccess you can install the application request routing module in IIS 7 and above. In IIS (Windows) you can set up default pages that come up when users go to particular sites.
2. You can also make that all of your pages are accessed through the same page using AJAX, or put all the content on the same page and hide it using CSS and display it with CSS and/or JS.

This is a very high level answer, because the specifics vary greatly from situation to situation.

Answer (score 6):

An easy way to do this, in case someone is still looking, is to use a full-screen iFrame. No matter where on the page your users are, they will always only see the main url. This used to be very popular back in the day, but it was a terrible practise in terms of usability.

```
<html><head>the stuff</head><body>
<iframe src="http://bakpinar.com/about/about-us.html" width=100% height=100%></iframe></body></html>
```

Write that into the index.html file at http://www.royaltyline.com

Answer (score 5):

It's not actually a folder name. It's rewritten URL.

To do such things you should redirect all requests to one file (index.php for example), then parse URL and basing on its parts, show particular file.

To redirect everything to index.php, use mod_rewrite module of Apache + .htaccess file.

To choose specific file you can implement one of several approaches. It's usually called routing in design patterns.

Completely other approach would be to use AJAX for reloading content. But it's not the way it was made on the website you gave as example.

In general there is a lot of information about routing urls in PHP on the web. Just do some research.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do by javascript.

```
<script>
       window.history.replaceState('','','/');
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are effectively looking to rewrite URLs. If your web server is Apache you will be able to use the rewriting module (mod_rewrite) to direct requests to http://bakpinar.com/about/ to http://bakpinar.com/about/about-us.html

If you are not running Apache, most web servers will serve index.html as the default page when requesting a directory, so renaming

```
about-us.html
```

to

```
index.html
```

and changing incoming links to

```
/about/about-us.html
```

to simply

```
/about/
```

Will give you the same results.