# Prevent href="#" link from changing the URL hash

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have a site that already takes advantage of the hash in the URL and I don't want it changed. When I use Zurb Foundation and use `href="#"` for the menu item, clicking on it removes the previous hash value.

How can I override this behavior?

**Update:** I think that it's better to stay with  element because when I change it, it changes the styling that is bound to that HTML element. I always prefer when using with a design framework to stay with the default conventions and not mess with overriding css attributes.

thanks.

Comment: I just follow the Zurb Foundation docs and they use href="#" in the menu item links

Comment: you can leave it empty, that still is valid

Comment: Could you paste your menu html? What’s the point of a menu that does nothing?

Comment: It does, it has onclick event on each <a> - I added it.

Comment: @user2587132 That was a good idea: it works great! Using href="" worked in my test right now: no more changing the url AND the link style looks correct..

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Please read up on  [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

You should (almost) never have `href="#"`. It is a link to an undefined anchor (which will be the top of the page). People who use it normally do so because they want to dangle JavaScript off it.

If you are going to have a link, then it should point to somewhere useful. Typically this will be another page that uses server side technology to get the same effect (albeit less quickly) as the JavaScript would give. You can then prevent the normal behaviour of the link.

For example:

```
<a href="/foo/bar" class="whatever">Foo: Bar</a>
```

With the script:

```
addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    if (ev.target.classList.contains('whatever')) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        loadWithAjax(ev.target.href);
    }   
});
```

If the JavaScript does something that can't have equivalent functionality expressed in a link, then you shouldn't be using a link in the first place. Use a `<button>`, and seriously consider adding it to the document using JavaScript/DOM instead of HTML.

(NB: Quite a lot of people want to support older browsers which don't recognise `classList` or `addEventListener` [checking browser support](http://caniuse.com/) and finding compatibility routines is left as an exercise for the reader. Using YUI, jQuery or similar is one approach for dealing with compatibility.)

Comment: Thanks. They use <a> for the style. If I remove it, it changes the style and therefore I prefer staying with their code conventions (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html) instead of massing around with css

Comment: _and seriously consider adding it to the document using JavaScript/DOM instead of HTML_, Why?

Comment: So you don't end up with a UI control that does nothing if the JS fails to load.

Comment: Sometimes you have to use `<a>` like for menu items in a dropdown list with [Spectre CSS](https://picturepan2.github.io/spectre/components.html#menus), and without the `href` the cursor does not change to `pointer` -- I suppose you could override the style but geez...

Comment: @user9645 — Looking at the example you link to … those are intended to be regular links, with `href` attributes containing useful URLs. They shouldn't use `href="#"` (the code in the example does, but only as a placeholder), so my answer stands.

Comment: I agree href="#" is UGLY.  It's hard to say with today's websites that links should be used as originally designed, only for reloading a different page (or place on the current page).

Answer (score 47):

You can listen for the click event and call [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop the browser from setting the hash.

Example with jQuery:

```
$('.mylink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: you can also `return false`, which is shorthand for both `event.preventDefault` and `event.stopPropagation`

Answer (score 41):

Instead of having `#` in href, you can use `javascript:;` in href which will not let the url change.

```
<a href="javascript:;">:Link</a>
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, one should prefer using a button element.

Comment: As I said above, I need to use <a> because foundation had a style attached to it and I prefer working using their styling and code conventions. (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html)

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using "#" use "javascript:void(0)"
See this link for more information [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0)

Answer (score 12):

Simply use this:

```
<a href="javascript:void()">text</a>
```

Comment: Sometimes you can't avoid using # target. For example when using Foundation components (tabs).

Answer (score 6):

I've done the following to prevent all the  tags with href="#" attribute perform navigation (Using JQuery):

```
$('a[href$="#"]').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;

        });
```

Comment: Is the dollar sign (`a[href$="#"]`) a typo?

Comment: @code it's the "attribute ends with" selector: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == '#') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Have below code in your default library. 
This will take the href value on click event and if hash (#) value found, then it will prevent the default event which will avoid redirecting to href value.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    if ($('#'+e.target.id).attr('href')=='#') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is `<a href="#hash" onclick="event.preventDefault();"></a>`

Answer (score 1):

The shortest I've come across is just to use an end of statement character:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="ouvrir">Newsletter</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little the same, using Javascript:

-> Replace

```
<a href=#foo class="ouvrir">Newsletter</a>
```

by:

```
<a href="javascript://" class="ouvrir">Newsletter</a>
```

And the Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('.ouvrir').click(function(event){
        window.location.href = "#foo";
        history.pushState('', document.title, window.location.pathname);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    window.history.replaceState('','','/',('#')[0]);
});

window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
    window.history.replaceState('','','/',('#')[0]);
});
```

Figured by combining [stckvrw's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346600/23572099), [Manjeet Kumar Nai's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57471763/23572099), and finding the [hashchange event at W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp).

Using pushState instead of replaceState should effect browser history entries and browser back button functionality, though for me it doesn't do the former.