# how to hide id from the url of the angularjs website

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, url, routes, seo

my current URL is:http://xyz.services/50/home.

i want to change this URL to http://xyz.services/.

can anyone help me how to do this.50 is the id of the page.

the whole content of the page come from the database.

below is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ pages.html?menu_id=$1&page_title=$2    
#RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ page.php?category=$1&product=$2    

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: if you don't tell us how are you doing your routing or don't provdie us any js,  how could you expect some help ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [How can i hide the full url of my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606433/how-can-i-hide-the-full-url-of-my-website)

This is not angular specific, but more of a configuration on the server you are deploying to.